# Turn off Default Retry Policy for Stepfuntions through CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Im creating a state machine using the below code

```
const taskState2 = new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, 'call 2nd lambda', {
      lambdaFunction: secondlambda,
      payloadResponseOnly: true
    });


    const taskState1 = new tasks.LambdaInvoke(this, 'Call 1st lambda', {
      lambdaFunction: first_lambda,
      payloadResponseOnly: true
    });

    //taskState1.addRetry(retryPolicy).next(taskState2);
     taskState1.next(taskState2);

    const mapstate = new sfn.Map(this, 'MapStateStepLambda', {
      itemsPath: '$.StepLambdaInput',
      maxConcurrency: 10,
    }).iterator(taskState1);

    const stateMachine = new sfn.StateMachine(this, 'MyStateMachine', {
      definition: mapstate,
      stateMachineName: `StateMachine`
    });
```

But when I deploy this, it is automatically attaching retry policy

```
"Call 1st lambda": {
            "Next": "Call 2nd lambda",
            "Retry": [
              {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                  "Lambda.ServiceException",
                  "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                  "Lambda.SdkClientException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
              }
            ],
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "**"
          },
```

when I attach some user-defined retry policy through cdk  `taskstate1.addRetryPolicy(mypolicy)`, I can still see default policy after deployment.
how can I remove default retry policy or edit the default retry policy using cdk.